# How to find the content in the comment using Xquery

Tags: xml, comments, xquery

I'm looking for a way to find the content of the comment in XML file using Xquery, I'm pretty new on it, so if there is anything wrong just let me know.

For example we have

```
<!-- comment_for_testing_xquery -->
```

How could I write the xquery to find the result as

```
comment_for_testing_xquery
```

Comment: Just updated my answer to more closely fit the edited requirements.

Comment: Some may be updated is that what I'm looking for is, for example, all the comment contents in a xml not matter where or what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `comment()` matches any comment node.

```
let $xml :=
<somexml>
  <a><!-- first comment --></a>
  <b><!-- second comment --></b>
</somexml>
for $c in $xml//comment()
return element comment { $c }
=>    
<comment><!-- first comment --></comment>
<comment><!-- second comment --></comment>
```

For more information, see the [node test explanation and examples the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#dt-node-test).

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, I have tried this yet. But last time I have used //*[comment()] trying to catch the comments, but the result looks wired. （Sorry I don't know xquery too much, just learn it since my colleague ask me about it） So i don't know what's going on with it.

Comment: `//*[comment()]` will return *elements with comment children*, not the comments themselves, which is what `//comment()` does. I'd recommend reading the link to the W3C spec I posted - that should clear up some of your misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks bro, that's exactly what I want. Since I have never used xquery before, so I may have lots of misunderstandings about that. Yeah, it's a great help. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: No prob. XML/XPath/XQuery/XSLT has many small details that take some adjustment time. But it's a very cool environment to work in.